# Error - The procedure entry point could not be located in libpango-1.0.dll - Gtk4 Build App

Tags: windows, gtk, pango, gtk4

[image: Error Displayed when Gtk app opened]

When i try to open the .exe file from the Gtk4 build i get the above error

```
The procedure entry point hb_ot_color_glyph_has_paint could not be
located in the dynamic link library
CAmsys64\mingw64\bin\liopango-1.0-0.dll
```

The build was finished successfully in vs code Build Task

I have installed all the gtk dependencies from msys2
Gtk4
base devel tools

I also have the libpango file specified in the error installed
I also deleted and reinstalled it again but the error still persists

Please give your input and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are programs in your systems that uses older version of pango library and their bin folders are in PATH. You can try to run console and set path to e.g. C: with:

```
set path=C:
```

and then run you program in the same console. If this helps, you are on the right way and just need to find which directory in PATH causes this error.

For me these poblem-causing programs with older libraries were xmlsec1 and graphviz.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to set your system `PATH` as described [here](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/latest/first_steps.html#missing-library) (change it with the correct gtk folder on your system)

```
set WEASYPRINT_DLL_DIRECTORIES=C:\GTK3\bin;
```

2. Ensure that **Graphviz** is not installed in your system (it was, in my case) as mentionned [here](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1339#issuecomment-976160876)

```
WHERE fontconfig.dll
```

If it is the case unsintall Graphviz en ensure it is not referenced in system `PATH`